# PDO/PHP: Better option for foreach

Tags: php, pdo

With the current code, it's very inefficient, confusing and seems to lack performance.

What could I improve in the MySQL Querying, or PHP to make this code easier and less [ all over the place ].

Are there better ways to replace what I'm currently trying to accomplish, which is to retrieve information from the database [ according to the iD ] and display them. My question is mostly based towards the foreach.

```
Posts table
+---------------+
|Post_iD        |
|message        |
|uid_fk         |
|tagged_people  |
|_iP            |
|created        |
|uploads        |
+---------------+
```

->load_messages.php
-->

```
<?php
    $lastid = "";
if ($lastid == '')
    $lastid = 0;

if ( $_iD ) {
    $updatesarray = $Wall->Updates($_iD, $lastid);
    $total        = $Wall->Total_Updates($_iD);
} else {
    $updatesarray = $Wall->Friends_Updates($_iD, $lastid);
    $total        = $Wall->Total_Friends_Updates($_iD);
}

if ($updatesarray) {
    foreach ($updatesarray as $data) {
        $post_iD     = $data['post_iD'];
        $orimessage = $data['message'];
        $message    = tolink(htmlcode($data['message']));
        $time       = $data['created'];
        $mtime      = date("g:i", $time);
        $_iUsername   = $data['_iUsername'];
        $uploads    = $data['uploads'];
        $msg_uid    = $data['uid_fk'];
?>  
    <ul class="_Om" id="stbody<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
        <li>
            <div class="_VC">
                <div class="stimg">
                    <img src="<?php echo $Profile_Pic;?>" class='picture' alt='<?php echo $_iUsername;?>'/>
                </div>      
                <div class="">
                    <b class="timeago">
                        <?php echo $_iUsername;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;
                            <a href='<?php echo $base_url ?>status/<?php echo $post_iD; ?>'title='<?php echo $time;?>' class="timeposted">
                                    <?php echo $mtime;?>
                            </a>
                    </b> 
                </div> 
                <div class="body_text">
                    <?php echo clear($message);?>
                </div>
                <?php
                    if ($uploads) {
                        echo "<div style='margin-top:10px'>";
                        $s = explode(",", $uploads);
                        foreach ($s as $a) {
                            $newdata = $Wall->Get_Upload_Image_Id($a);
                            if ($newdata)
                                echo "<a href='uploads/" . $newdata['image_path'] . "' rel='facebox'><img src='uploads/" . $newdata['image_path'] . "' class='imgpreview' /></a>";
                        }
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>

                <div class="stexpandbox">
                    <div class="stexpand<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
                        <?php
                            if (textlink($orimessage)) {
                            $link = textlink($orimessage);
                            echo Expand_URL($link); 
                            }
                        ?>     
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ($_iD == $msg_uid) { ?>
                    <a class="stdelete" href="#" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>" title="Delete Update"></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>      
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php } if ($total > $perpage) { ?>
        <div id="more<?php echo $post_iD;?>" class="morebox">
            <a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">More</a>
        </div>
<?php } } else echo '<h3 id="noupdates">No Updates!</h3>';?>
```

Database query `(Updates,Total_Updates,Friends_Updates,Total_Friends_Updates)`

```
http://pastie.org/private/j66vwnsfyk1fai7zlnrrg
```

Comment: Your not using prepared query's, so your code is not safe from sql injection. Dependent on where your getting `$_iD, $lastid` values.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you my thoughts.

**It's very inefficient**

Recode from scratch and hopefully you'll find some design flaws you made. Perhaps you could stop:

```
 $post_iD     = $data['post_iD'];
```

from what I can see, this stuff are in the same loop, so just use the associative array instead.

**confusing**

Try using the MVC architecture pattern and add some comments to you code. The MVC should help a lot though and functions can go a very long way.

And the:

```
        <?php if ($_iD == $msg_uid) { ?>
                <a class="stdelete" href="#" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>" title="Delete Update"></a>
        <?php } ?>
```

Is that anchor for deleting or is it not deleting? Because it seems to be missing some text. Unless the CSS that styles it is on this same page at the top? What you are doing is no different to embedding css from my point of view. I think

```
<?php

   if ($_iD == $msg_uid) { 

      echo '<a class="stdelete" href="#" id="'.$post_iD.'" title="Delete Update">Delete</a>';

   }

?>
```

is a lot more readable to most programmers.

**Lack performance**

Plan your system ahead of time, write better queries that will only select what it needs and if that fails, determine how important posts are. If it's not the end of the world if you loose a couple. Check out NoSQL database. But from your submitted code, it would be the guilty party for *Lack of performance* and not MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer.